# Angular js 1.7.6 issue with Asp.Net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I am facing an issue with AngularJS upgrade work. I am upgrading from 1.7.5 to 1.7.6 of AngularJS on Asp.Net Webform application with .net 3.5.

Webform by default emits __dopostback with other important hiddenfields (__EVENTTARGET, __EVENTATTR, __VIEWSTATE etc.) Issue comes when webform tries to post the form on button click/ dropdown selection change.

__dopostback unable to send any of the hidden fields values on server side.

Anywork around is highly appreciated.

Comment: Wondering why you have used AngularJS in a Web Forms project. They simply don't get along.

Comment: I am also wondering the same thing as Delphi. You already have a UI framework - Forms - in your project. and you are using one more. it does not compute.